# If P is equal to NP, then what happens to the problems those can be solved in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

Suppose that an algorithm $A$ is able to solve a problem in **NP** in polynomial time.
Does this effect the good old sorting, searching, shortest path, minimum spanning tree etc. algorithms? 
Can this improvement pave the way for a $O(n)$ sort or $O(log^*n)$ search?

Edit: P vs. NP problem can also be interpreted as "[can we find something without searching?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msp2y_Y5MLE)" that's why I wonder if that effects the other problems as well.

Comment: "Suppose that an algorithm A is able to solve a problem in NP in polynomial time. " -- that's nothing special, we know (many?) thousands of such. I take it you mean NP-complete? From the way you phrase your question, I think you should take a looks at [our reference material](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/845#845).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not clear what you mean by an algorithm which is able to solve *any* problem in NP; usually one algorithm solves one problem. However, given a polynomial time algorithm for solving some NP-complete problem, you can solve any NP problem in polynomial time. However, every problem will require a different algorithm.

This doesn't necessarily affect problems which are already in P. Indeed, we have *unconditional* lower bounds on search and sort which show that no $O(n)$ sort or $O(\log^* n)$ search algorithm exist, in restricted computation models. Even when tight bounds are not available (or when you consider a computation model for which good lower bounds are not available), there is no reason to assume that an algorithm for NP-complete problems is relevant.

On the other hand, if P=NP then *more difficult* problems are affected: you can show using a padding argument that P=NP implies EXP=NEXP, for example. But the implication doesn't go the other way around.

Comment: I have used the wrong word, sorry. And thank you for your answer.